# How to get the result of a js function called with <script>?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, timer

I am currently working on a quizz page with code people have already done before. I have to add a timer and when the timer is done, I have to send a form.
I have decided to make my function a boolean to get the result directly with the return. When it's true, then the timer is over. But the problem is 
I call a js function in the html and I don't know how to get the return result.

This is the part of the code I need help on :

```
echo '<body>
  <div class="body">';
       if($type=='t'){
             $timer = false;
             echo '<div id="clockdiv"></div>';
             echo '<script language="javascript">timer = setInterval(timer(), 10000)</script>';
             echo $timer;
         }
```

And my js function :

```
function timer(){
          var running = false;
          var time_in_minutes = 0.3;
          var current_time = Date.parse(new Date());
          var deadline = new Date(current_time + time_in_minutes*60*1000);
          function run_clock(id,endtime){
            var clock = document.getElementById(id);
            function update_clock(){
                          function time_remaining(endtime){
                             var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
                             var seconds = Math.floor( (t/1000) % 60 );
                             var minutes = Math.floor( (t/1000/60) % 60 );
                             var hours = Math.floor( (t/(1000*60*60)) % 24 );
                             var days = Math.floor( t/(1000*60*60*24) );
                             return {'total':t, 'days':days, 'hours':hours, 'minutes':minutes, 'seconds':seconds};
                          }
        var t = time_remaining(endtime);
        clock.innerHTML = 'minutes: '+t.minutes+'<br>seconds: '+t.seconds;
        if(t.total<=0){ 
                  clearInterval(timeinterval);
                  clock.innerHTML = 'Temps écoulé';
                  running = true;
                 }
    }
    update_clock(); // run function once at first to avoid delay
    var timeinterval = setInterval(update_clock,1000);
}
          run_clock('clockdiv',deadline);
          return running;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below code

```
<body>
<div class="body">
    <?php 
        if($type=='t'){
            $timer = false;
    ?>
        <div id="clockdiv"></div>
        <script language="javascript">timer = setInterval(timer(), 10000)</script>
    <?php 
            echo $timer; 
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I can't use it directly because the code is between [insert_php] and I can't change all the structure for my piece of code.
Furthermore, I need to add that if and only if type = t then I add the div, and the script